# Traversing Nested Dicts in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm using the excellent [Julia Mat File reader](https://github.com/JuliaIO/MAT.jl) to read a mat file with the structure similar to test2

```
Dict1 = Dict("a" => [1,3], "b" => 2, "c" => "Hello")
test2=Dict("test"=>Dict1,"a"=>[2,4])
```

With the read command I can access Dict1 like this:

```
using MAT
read(file, "test")
```

But I'd also like to access variables within Dict1, like "a" or "b".

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_1 = Dict("a" => [1,3], "b" => 2, "c" => "Hello")

dict_2 = Dict("test" => dict_1, "a" => [2,4])

@show dict_2["test"]["b"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While that does works for dictionaries, for some reason it doesn't work for the MAT read function; I think the main issue is the read function only takes one string variable.